# Amazon Cognito hosted UI impossible to iframe?

Tags: amazon-cognito

I tried, but in headers `X-Frame-Options: deny` and I do not found any way to configure this inside backend UI.

[image: codepen amazon cognito hosted ui iframe X-Frame-Options deny]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how much of an "answer" this is, but I don't yet have enough reputation to comment and I think this is relevant.  The accepted answer doesn't really address iframes at all.

I can't find it documented anywhere, but my guess is that AWS doesn't allow this due to click-jacking concerns.

The FAQ page for Microsoft's Azure AD B2C (a product similar to Cognito) explains why *they* don't allow their hosted pages to be embedded in iframes:

> No, for security reasons, Azure AD B2C pages cannot be opened within
>   an iFrame. Our service communicates with the browser to prohibit
>   iFrames. The security community in general and the OAUTH2
>   specification, recommend against using iFrames for identity
>   experiences due to the risk of click-jacking.

*Source:*
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-faqs

Comment: Few years have passed and now that Azure AD B2C supports embedding in iframes (the feature is in public preview).https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/faq?tabs=app-reg-ga#can-my-app-open-up-azure-ad-b2c-pages-within-an-iframe

Answer (score 3):

> I do not found any way to configure this inside backend UI.

TLDR: Looks like you can't configure it.

### How is `iframe` Embedding Blocked?

How did AWS prevent `iframe` embedding? As you pointed out:

> in headers `X-Frame-Options: deny`

AWS use the `x-frame-options: DENY` header on purpose to block `iframe` embedding and thus defend against ClickJacking, as hypothesised in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46737625/5134722). Here is a quote from [rachitdhall](https://github.com/rachitdhall), who at the time of writing is a "Software Development Manager working for Amazon Cognito":

> X-Frame Options is used to prevent ClickJacking.

[Here](https://github.com/amazon-archives/amazon-cognito-identity-js/issues/599#issuecomment-345347022) is the source of that comment on GitHub.

Indeed, if I log into my AWS account and navigate to my Cognito hosted UI in my web browser, I can still see today `x-frame-options: DENY` as one of the headers coming in. I won't go into what this does - instead readers should refer to the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options).

The comment appears on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/amazon-archives/amazon-cognito-identity-js/issues/599), which is still open at the time of writing, so presumably AWS have not today implemented the feature to allow Cognito users to enable embedding of the hosted UI in their custom pages.

### Why Don't AWS Allow their Customer to Configure the Headers?

Again returning to this [GitHub comment](https://github.com/amazon-archives/amazon-cognito-identity-js/issues/599#issuecomment-345347022):

> We have heard the request to allow IFRAMES from other customers and will consider it in future updates to the service.

It leaves you wondering, almost 5 years on, why is this not implemented "yet"?

I'll try to speculate, but note that I do not represent AWS and cannot speak on their behalf. All I am doing in the following is pointing out some difficulties that make the implementation of this feature non-trivial; perhaps less trivial than it might seem at first glance.

#### No CSP Headers

Firstly, I do not see any Content-Security-Policy (CSP) headers coming from AWS yet. From the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options), note that:

> The Content-Security-Policy HTTP header has a [frame-ancestors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors) directive which obsoletes this header for supporting browsers.

Maybe we will see CSP headers over the next few years. But this may or may not result in a customisable `iframe` embedding feature for the hosted UI. I'll give some reasons in the following sections.

#### Limitation

`x-frame-options` only allows two values: `DENY` and `SAMEORIGIN`. Neither would suffice to allow a customer to embed the hosted UI on their custom page, which is presumably a different origin to that of the hosted UI e.g. `example.com` vs `auth.example.com`. Note: I believe this is impossible, even using the deprecated approach of setting `document.domain` as proposed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63957359/5134722), because doing so requires the new origin to be:

> its current domain or a superdomain of its current domain

This again, according to the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

So since AWS manages Cognito, and since AWS are hardly going to allow use of a deprecated feature with security risks, we can assume the `document.domain` of `auth.example.com` can't be modified, and on the other hand the domain of `example.com` can't be modified to `auth.example.com` vs because that's a subdomain, not self or a superdomain.

#### Security / Responsibility

Since `x-frame-options` won't work, presumably the way for AWS to grant their customers this feature would be to allow them to edit the [frame-ancestors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors) directive in the CSP header of the hosted UI; this would assume AWS adds a CSP header of course. But then AWS is handing over some more control to its customers and this somewhat blurs who is responsible for the security of the hosted UI. This would probably mean a lot of work for AWS revising their [shared responsibility model](https://aws.amazon.com/compliance/shared-responsibility-model/) for the Cognito hosted UI.

#### Backwards Compatibility

Even if AWS do add the CSP header, and even if they do allow customers to edit it, there is still the issue of backwards-compatibility. AWS will likely be loth to completely discard the `x-frame-options` header, in case some browsers do not yet process the `frame-ancestors` CSP directive.

For browsers that do support the `frame-ancestors` CSP directive, then according to [W3 docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/#frame-ancestors-and-frame-options):

> the frame-ancestors policy SHOULD be enforced and the X-Frame-Options policy SHOULD be ignored.

But what if it isn't ignored? And what about older browsers that don't process the `frame-ancestors` CSP directive yet? For such browsers, the `frame-ancestors` CSP directive will be ignored, the `x-frame-options` denial will kick in, and the functionality won't work. And then AWS will likely get a bunch of complaints from their customers about a feature that's broken.

Answer (score 2):

You can check this post on Github: https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js/issues/508. In ildar-icoosoft's respond, he showed how he managed to put the hosted ui in a pop-up window. Hope this can help

Comment: could you add this as a feature request to the hosted UI? The possibility to run an alternate version inside a dialog?

Comment: We got a lot of feedbacks about customized domain name. It is on our roadmap.

Comment: @SummerGuo any updates about this feature? Is there a way now to use iframes?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else is looking for this: it turns out cognito will run in an iframe if you set the iframe's document.domain to amazoncognito.com. Of course, then the underlying resource that you're trying to load must run inside the iframe with that domain. If that underlying resource uses cookies, they won't work if 3rd party cookies are disabled on the user's browser.

Comment: It is not a working solution. Please, use the comment option next time for answers like that.

Comment: Got an example? Not sure exactly what/how you're talking about.

Comment: Document.domain has been deprecated and is a security risk anyway.

Comment: +1 on @TK-421's comment, and link to the relevant documentation warning about the dangers of document.domain: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/domain.