# Possible reasons for invalid_token from AWS Cognito on https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/tokeninfo

Tags: oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito

I believe I am missing something with the implicit grant process and access tokens in aws cognito.

To this point:

1. Have a user pool, with a client app configured for implicit flow and scopes openid, profile, aws.cognito.signin.user.admin
2. Used a [stack overview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45926339/cognito-hosted-ui) and the [official documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/login-with-amazon/choose-authorization-grant.html) and [older white papers](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/G/01/mobile-apps/dex/login-with-amazon/login-with-amazon._TTH_.pdf) to achieve:
3. Login process that redirects to aws cognito UI, and back to my app, with tokens and other information in the fragment portion of the URL.
4. The access_token value parses at jwt.io and signature checks out using the [aws jwt tool](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-support-tools/tree/master/Cognito/decode-verify-jwt)

Problem:

The [recommended step](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/login-with-amazon/obtain-customer-profile.html) is to "verify that the access token belongs to us" through the tokeninfo api call. 
When I attempt to call tokeninfo  via javascript code and testing via postman (using: https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/tokeninfo?access_token=eyJraWQiOiJoVFBa... )

I get the result:

```
{
"error_description": "The request has an invalid parameter : access_token",
"error": "invalid_token"
}
```

and an http header:

```
x-amzn-errortype: InvalidTokenException:http://internal.amazon.com/coral/com.amazon.panda/
```

Variants I have tried:

- I have tried calls directly to the user profile (using Authorization header, and query string and x-amz-access-token header).
- I have tried adjust parameter names (error becomes "access_token required" or something like that
- I have tried adjusting scopes in the user pool
- I have tried adding resource servers (though I am not there yet...)

The redirect after login looks like this:

```
  https://staging.example.com/loginresult.html#id_token=eyJraWQiO<tokenremoved>&access_token=eyJraWQiOiJoVFBa<tokenremoved>&expires_in=3600&token_type=Bearer&state=whateverdevwants
```

The parsed values of the token (through jwt.io) are:

```
{
"sub": "5510a27d-ebcb-4883-8680-a66fd0462279",
"token_use": "access",
"scope": "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin openid profile",
"iss": "https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_OF5OOfdx0",
"exp": 1519352461,
"iat": 1519348861,
"version": 2,
"jti": "31950a91-e2a5-4060-8c31-977f49802d35",
"client_id": "3iuhnprmod0josge24ogarecfp",
"username": "5510a27d-ebcb-4883-8680-a66fd0462279"
}
```

*Update:* As answered below: just don't do this, it is conflating jwt tokens from cognito with whatever "Login With Amazon" was using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example you refer to from [Amazon](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/login-with-amazon/obtain-customer-profile.html) they encode the access token using `urllib.quote_plus` for example in their PHP example.

Make sure you are URL encoding the access token too in your javascript code with `encodeURI`.

Also an error may be returned if the token has expired so make sure you verify a newly-minted token. Expiry is 3600 seconds - so make sure the token is less than an hour old.

**EDIT**

Looks like the documentation for Cognito is very different from the LWA (login with amazon) auth flow. The tokens in the examples you linked to aren't even JWT tokens!

The [Cognito documentation here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html) explains how to verify the JWT token.
Checkout the `Using ID Tokens and Access Tokens in your Web APIs` paragraph.

Comment: Thanks, yes, was keeping track of the time to use in the first hour. And was encoding with encodeURIComponent (though the access_token didn't have encodable characters as far as I could tell...)

Comment: updated my answer - it looks like the official documentation you linked to is for LWA and very differnt from AWS Cognito. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. I found when I just used them against AWS API with cognito authorizers it just worked; not sure if/how to validate jwt tokens for cognito (may just signature checks), but this is not the way to do it. Thanks!