# Use the token response from SAML authentication with User Pools to retrieve AWS Temporary Access keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-userpools

How do I use the token response from SAML authentication with User Pools to retrieve AWS Temporary Access keys and Make API Gateway Calls?

I have configured a Cognito User Pool with an associated App client. I have configured Okta as a 3rd Party SAML Identity provider. Using the Amazon hosted login `https://[cognito domain name]/login?response_type=token&client_id=[your App client id]&redirect_uri=[your App client redirect URL]` I am able to be redirected to my ReactJS application with the `#access_token` in the header.

I am trying to now user the `#access_token` to call API gateway. I have been following this [guide](https://github.com/UWFosterIT/aws-cognito/wiki/Step-2:-AWS-API-Gateway-Cognito-User-Pool-Authorizer) as well as aws-amplify. To my understanding I need to use the `#access_token` to get AWS access keys to make the call to API gateway.

I am trying to do this with the following code:

```
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
IdentityPoolId: 'us-east-1:xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx',
   Logins: {
      'cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_xxxxxx': #access_token
   }
});
```

but not sure how this integrates with aws-amplify, and I have not successfully retrieved AWS temporary access keys to make API Gateway calls.

I previously had this working using users in the Cognito User Pool but now I need to include Okta as an identity provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found I needed the `#id_token` rather than the `#access_token` to accomplish what I was trying to do. I enabled the `#id_token` by selecting the following options in my Cognito Pool App Client Settings: [image]

I was then able to follow [Cognito hosted UI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45926339/5787099).